# Unable to iterate for loop in jquery properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 div elements in my html each of which have a checkbox. When I click the delete button the divs with checked checkboxes should be deleted. However I find that when I check all the checkboxes the last div remains undeleted. I am sure that the last iteration is occuring as I have checked that using alert boxes. However the last iteration mysteriously stops somewhere in between without deleting the last div. The class of my 3 divs are "0","1" & "2". The following is my function:

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('myCheckbox');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked==true){ 
      $("."+i).remove();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to do looping from end to beginning:

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('myCheckbox');
  for(var i = checkboxes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if(checkboxes[i].checked==true){ 
      $("."+i).remove();
    }
  }
});
```

Working [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/bbv2dw47/14/).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working if you convert your live collection of nodes to an array and then ensure that you reduce the length of the array by one every time you delete an element:

```
$("#delete").click(function () {
  var checkboxes = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByName('myCheckbox'), 0);
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
      $('.' + i).remove();
      n--;
    }
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tm1b6sc2/17/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you remove the div in for loop the number of elements in the node array also reduce so the last element does not get deleted.Here is a way to implement what you are doing

```
var arr = [];
$("#delete").click(function(){
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('myCheckbox');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked==true){ 
        arr.push(i);
    }
  }
     removeDiv(arr);
});
function removeDiv(elems){
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
        $("."+i).remove();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This way, when we iterate in the click event, the number of elements in the variable `checkboxes` remain same.Later we remove the required once.You will need to modify the code based on your neds as the `var arr = [];` is not reset and will have `i` pushed in on every click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <html>
      <head>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      </head>

            <body>
                       <div class="0">

                           <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />

                        </div>

                       <div class="1">

                           <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />

                       </div>

                      <div class="2">
                           <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
                      </div>

                  <input type="button" id="delete" value="delete" />


              <script>
                          $("#delete").click(function(){
                                     $("div input").each(function(index, element) {
                                             if(element.checked){
                                                        $(this).parent().remove()
                                                                }
                                       })
                           });
              </script>


             </body>
           </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, this does address the (perceived) overly-complicated solution you've chosen. I'd suggest changing to:

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
    $('input.myCheckbox').each(function (i) {
        $('.' + i).remove();
    });
});
```

But note that, as yet, it can be tricky to have a numeral as the first character of a class-name, and may require an escape sequence:

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
    $('input.myCheckbox').each(function (i) {
        $('.\3' + i).remove();
    });
});
```

References:

- "[CSS Escapes](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)."
- [`each()`](http://api.jQuery.com/each/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code you posted worked fine when i did a fiddle with it, but i think a better approach is to use jquery instead of for-loops and put the inputs inside the divs to provide context so you know which div is deleted by which checkbox.

The deletion can then be reduced to a one-liner:

html:

```
<div class="deletable">
    0
    <input name="deletediv" type="checkbox"></input>
</div>
<div class="deletable">
    1
    <input name="deletediv" type="checkbox"></input>
</div>
<div class="deletable">
    2
    <input name="deletediv" type="checkbox"></input>
</div>

<button id="delete">delete</button>
```

js:

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
    $(".deletable input[name='deletediv']:checked").parent().remove();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9gLfL0r/)

EDIT:

if you need to do things with the element before removing it from dom, you can use $.each:

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
    $(".deletable input[name='deletediv']:checked").parent().each(function() {
        console.log("$(this) is a div with a checked checkbox");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: The looping from the end of the array worked for me. Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: I would still recommend making use of jQuery for these kind of things since you have it in your script, it will simplify a lot of things